# Advanced SQL Query - Universal Temporary Table or Something Else?

Tags: sql, oracle, global, temporary

I am fairly new to Oracle SQL Queries, and have run into a problem I can both not solve, nor describe well to Google/StackOverflow's search bar to find an answer.

I have two tables.

For simplicity, let's say Table A has two variables, both of which are not unique within the table.

```
|Order |Feature|
|1     |      A|
|1     |      B|
|1     |      C|
|2     |      B|
|2     |      C|
|3     |      A|
|3     |      C|
|4     |      A|
|4     |      B|
```

Table B contains the Order variable, and a date variable. In this case, the Order variable is unique.

```
|Order |     Date|
|1     |  Aug 1st|
|2     |  Aug 1st|
|3     |  Aug 1st|
|4     |July 31st|
```

Here is the tricky part (to me). I want Table A, but without any orders that:

1. Do not contain an instance of Feature "A"
2. Fall within the month of August in Table B

It would look like:

```
|Order |Feature|
|1     |      A|
|1     |      B|
|1     |      C|
|3     |      A|
|3     |      C|
```

I have tried to get this to work with a Global Local Table, unsuccessfully. In that strategy I would first pull all Orders with "A" into a table, and then pull all Features with an Order in the temporary table, and with the Date in August.

Alternatively, I assume there is a more efficient way without a temporary Table, but my experience is limited.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to accomplish this (join with GROUP BY, IN , EXISTS, ANY) none of which require temp tables or similar techniuques.

I'm choosing in because it's easy to follow.

```
Select order, feature 
From tableA a
WHERE a.Order  in (select order from TableA where Feature = 'A' )
and a.order in (select order from tableB where be extract(month from date) = 8  )
```

Comment: You don't need `and order is not null` anyway. You are confusing IN with NOT IN where nulls indeed can be a problem.

Comment: I think `month(date)`should be `extract(month from date)` in Oracle.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner doh that's right don't know what I was thinking

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to do a subquery to find order in your criteria and then select the information you want.

Try this :

```
SELECT a.order, a.feature
FROM tableA a
INNER JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT a1.order
            FROM tableA a1 
            INNER JOIN tableB b 
                 ON b.order = a1.order
            WHERE month(b.date) = 8
                 AND a1.feature = 'A'
           ) c on c.order = a.order;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do it by using an analytic function to test for the presence of the 'A' feature, and then join to the other table to get the dt.

As written in your question, I think this is what you're after:

```
with table_a as (select 1 ord, 'A' feature from dual union all
                 select 1 ord, 'B' feature from dual union all
                 select 1 ord, 'C' feature from dual union all
                 select 2 ord, 'B' feature from dual union all
                 select 2 ord, 'C' feature from dual union all
                 select 3 ord, 'A' feature from dual union all
                 select 3 ord, 'C' feature from dual union all
                 select 4 ord, 'A' feature from dual union all
                 select 4 ord, 'B' feature from dual),
     table_b as (select 1 ord, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                 select 2 ord, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                 select 3 ord, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                 select 4 ord, to_date('31/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                 select 5 ord, to_date('31/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual),
         res as (select ta.ord,
                        ta.feature,
                        max(case when ta.feature = 'A' then 'A' end) over (partition by ta.ord) a_present,
                        tb.dt
                 from   table_a ta
                        inner join table_b tb on (ta.ord = tb.ord))
select ord,
       feature
from   res
where  a_present is not null
and    to_char(dt, 'mm') != '08';

       ORD FEATURE
---------- -------
         4 A      
         4 B
```

However, the results you indicated show that you actually wanted results that had contained an 'A' in each group and did fall within the month of August

```
with table_a as (select 1 ord, 'A' feature from dual union all
                 select 1 ord, 'B' feature from dual union all
                 select 1 ord, 'C' feature from dual union all
                 select 2 ord, 'B' feature from dual union all
                 select 2 ord, 'C' feature from dual union all
                 select 3 ord, 'A' feature from dual union all
                 select 3 ord, 'C' feature from dual union all
                 select 4 ord, 'A' feature from dual union all
                 select 4 ord, 'B' feature from dual),
     table_b as (select 1 ord, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                 select 2 ord, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                 select 3 ord, to_date('01/08/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                 select 4 ord, to_date('31/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual union all
                 select 5 ord, to_date('31/07/2015', 'dd/mm/yyyy') dt from dual),
         res as (select ta.ord,
                        ta.feature,
                        max(case when ta.feature = 'A' then 'A' end) over (partition by ta.ord) a_present,
                        tb.dt
                 from   table_a ta
                        inner join table_b tb on (ta.ord = tb.ord))
select ord,
       feature
from   res
where  a_present is not null
and    to_char(dt, 'mm') = '08';

       ORD FEATURE
---------- -------
         1 A      
         1 B      
         1 C      
         3 A      
         3 C
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not comfortable with analytic function and subqueries (you should be, but your question indicates you might not be), you can do this with straight joins - nothing special:

```
SELECT a2.ord, a2.feature
FROM table_a a1 
inner join table_b b on b.ord = a1.ord 
inner join table_a a2 on a2.ord = a1.ord 
where b.dt between to_date('01-AUG-2015') and last_day(to_date('01-AUG-2015') + (86399/86400))
 and a1.feature = 'A';
```

Basically, you go to table A first to get just the lines with feature A, then you go to table A again to get all the lines for those orders.

Your post did not indicate whether one order could have the same feature twice.  I'm assuming no, but if yes, then you'll need to SELECT DISTINCT instead of SELECT.

Personally, I would probably write this with the analytic functions as described above.  I'm adding this alternative just because it uses very basic SQL only.